# How to handle validation of illegal argument

Tags: c#, validation, exception

I know this problem has already been addressed on the site. Though, there are many different opinions and I'd like to understand it deeper to know how to face some particular situations.
Let us say I have the following code. I will write in C#, though it isn't a strictly related C# question.

```
class Player
{
    private int dexterity;
    public int Dexterity{
        get => dexterity;
        set{
           //Here I need to validate: problem 2
           dexterity = value;
           UpdateArmorClass(); //Armor class should be modified any time dex is
        }
    private int armorClass;

    public Player(int dex){
        Dexterity = dex;
    }

    private void UpdateArmorClass(){
        //Should I validate here? Problem 3
        armorClass = 10 + Dexterity;
    }
}
//Here is main with user input: problem 1
```

Let us say a user is asked to input its detxterity, **which must be non negative**, to create its character. Now I face three situations:

- **Problem 1: user input validation**: reading around, I've been convinced that I shuold never use exceptions to validate user input, since it's something that occurs very often. I think I can solve this problem by using a boolean isValid and ask the user again to input his value if it's false. Is this a good solution?
- **Problem 2: validation in a constructor**: *well, it's not really in the constructor, I put it in the setter of dexterity, which will be called by the constructor*. A priori, there would be no need of checking this, because, if the user input has already been validated, the data will be correct. *Though*, I may create Player somewhere else in the code (so I want to check on *programmer level* and not on *user level*) and dexterity shuold never be allowed to be negative. Here I am facing the big dilemma: **use exceptions or not?**
  I'd personally use them to stop the program from generating an *invalid object*. Though, *many discourage exception usage due to its expensiveness*. The only solution I can think of is to give default values anytime the given values are wrong. Though, it seems a *tricky solution* to me, since the program will go ahead undisturbed and I will not know a default value has been put (which may be wrong for my situation). So, the real question: should I use exceptions to handle situations like this in costructors (or setters)?
- **Problem 3: validation in a method**: now I know also armorClass should never be allowed to be negative. In my situation, I have a private method which updates armorclass anytime dexterity is modified. So **there's really no need** here to validate again. Now assume I make another class which is used to make a simple fight and I have the method displayed at the end of this post, which calculates probability of being hit. It expects to get some armorClass value, though I may be another programmer and cannot know if the armorClass in Player has already been validated. So I check if it's non negative. Throwing an exception for such a check seems to much, though if I check its non-negativity I must return a default value when the armorClass is negative, which seems tricky. **What should I do in this situation?**

Here's the last method:

```
public float Hit(int armorClass){
    if(armorClass >=0) //calculate probability of being hit
    //return probability
}
```

*Bonus question* (related to the previous questions of course): is instantiating a new exception really that expensive? Or is it only the try-catch part? To me, it seems like instantiating a new object and that's all. Though, I may be wrong and that's why many say you shuould not use exceptions if not really needed.

Comment: not related to your question: in setter, `Dexterity = dexterity;` should be `dexterity = Dexterity;`

Comment: Yeah, actually that was a typo. I use `dexterity = value` in C#, but I assume that results in the same thing as you wrote.

Comment: sure, `dexterity = value`: my typo as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here I am facing the big dilemma: use exceptions or not? I'd
>   personally use them to stop the program from generating an invalid
>   object. Though, many discourage exception usage due to its
>   expensiveness.

Use the exception. Exceptions are only expensive when raised and it's always better to raise an exception than to end up with corrupted objects. If your values come from user input, handle invalid values where you acquire it from user, separately. This way, you can safely call those methos/set values from code and you are not raising exceptions when user inputs invalid values. Additionaly, sometimes there are special values that you may want to let to use, that should not be allowed for user to input.

Problem 3:
If your private field is always validated before set, there is no point in checking if its valid on get. In your code example, adding `10` to any non-negative number will always return non-negative value.

Bonus question:
All raised exceptions have to be handled somewhere, so I dont think it does matter if its the raising exception part which is expensive, or the catching part.

Comment: Many thanks for your clear answer! What about last example (with the public method in another class)? Would you check the armor class there? Like, if armorclass is positive: calculate probability; else, do nothing/return default value (e.g. 0). I always find it hard to imagine the consequences of this kind of validation. Though, it seems the only solution in that situation.

Comment: Well, it's a public method, so it may not be the best idea to assume your parameters will always be valid. When it comes to what to do exactly, it depends on the logic. If in some cases your "armorClass" could be nagative (like ie. some enemy modifier that treats all your armor like it's 1 level lower) and returning 0 is valid, expected value for this method, returning it is perfectly fine. If you `armorClass` should never be negative, then throwing an exception or using `Debug.Assert` is ok. You can use the latest to not crash you app in production, but clearly see something is wrong i debug.

Comment: Thanks for all your advice. That was really helpful :-)